# How to integrate a Qt application into Eclipse as a plugin?

Tags: eclipse, qt, eclipse-plugin

I have a Qt 4.7.x application developed in C++. This is actually a graphical state machine editor with automatic code generation for embedded systems. When I announced the tool to the embedded community, the first question asked was "does it run in Eclipse?"

So, my questions are:

1. What options do I have? Can I run a C++ GUI application inside Eclipse without any modifications or with minimal modifications?
2. If running without modifications is not an option or is awkward, how do I need to repackage a Qt application to make it run in Eclipse?
3. My Qt application is using dock windows, toolbars, and MDI (multiple document interface). Do I need to adjust the user interface structure for Eclipse and how do I go about it?
4. I am mostly interested in deploying the application on Windows. But my application runs also on Linux and Mac OS X. How do I deploy a native C++ application with Eclipse on these operating systems?

Any specific examples for Qt would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Really what you need to worry about is integrating Qt with the SWT toolkit. They traditionally don't get along too well. There have been a number of different attempts to make Java and Qt cooperate, and a smaller number to make Qt and AWT cooperate, and the tiniest number of all to make Qt and SWT cooperate. Still, there are a few things you can look at that could serve as a foundation for your project. Perhaps the most promising is [SWT/Qt](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/swtqt/), which is a project to build a Qt-based SWT implementation. The last I looked at it, it really wasn't a realistic option, but it's been very active since.